# If I alter a table to add a partition will I lose data in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, partition

I am not sure about altering a table to create a new partition as I am afraid I will lose data. If a table in an Oracle SQL DB is already partitioned but I am adding a new partition, will the existing data in the table be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No you dont lose the data

You can create list partition and expand it on default partition

for example if your partion is date:

```
alter table your_table split partition PDEFAULT values(TO_DATE('20161206','yyyymmdd')) into ( partition P20161206,partition PDEFAULT)
```

Comment: thanks, by default partition, do you mean last partition?

Comment: you can split your partition

Answer (score 1):

The only ALTER TABLE partitioning commands that can destroy data are DROP and TRUNCATE.

The EXCHANGE partition command can move data from a table partition to a different table, and vice-versa.

ADD, MOVE, COALESCE, RENAME, SPLIT, and MERGE do not change the table's data, although COALESCE, SPLIT, and MERGE can change the partition or subpartition in which data is stored.